# POST or not? render_to_response() or render()?

Tags: django, render

I am very new user of Django. I would like to send an email (for fax) in clicking on a button. So I have created the method `send_fax` in the view `CustomerRequestUpdateView`. I am a bit confusing here. Does this method have to use a POST request? How could I render 'send_fax' to my template? I would like that method could be implemented in the class directly.

```
class CustomerRequestUpdateView(RequestUpdateView):
    template_name = 'loanwolf/customers/request.html'
    url_namespace = 'customers'

    def send_fax(self):

        subject = 'The contract of %s' % self.customer.email_user
        contact_message = 'This is just a test for later on during this project'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_email = [from_email, ]

        send_mail(
            subject,
            contact_message,
            from_email,
            to_email,
            fail_silently=False,
        )

    return #render(request, template_name, context) render_to_pdf()
```

I thought I could use `render_to_response()` or just `render()`, but my method use `self`, not `request`. Could anyone be able to help me here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: that method won't do anything as it stands whatsoever, only functions called named one of the http requests will be executed

Comment: Relevant: [Dispatch code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L78)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to show on the page?
You do not need a Class based View to do that (you can use it though). You can simply write:

```
def my_view(request):
    send_mail(paramters here)
    # Add whatever object you think you'd need on the page in the context (the 
    # third paramter of render {}.
    # render adds request to response so it's preferred. render_to_response may be deprecated soon. If it has not been already
    return render(request, 'loanwolf/customers/request.html', {})
```